# My catalog app shows a blank page, what should I do?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm creating a website in django, and currently I'm building a online catalog of items. But when I run it, it just shows a blank page.

my code is given below:

catalog\models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class itemType(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):        
        return reverse('catalog:item_list_by_category',                       
        args=[self.slug])
        
class itemStage(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class item(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Name of the item', db_index=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, null=True)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Description', blank=True, db_index=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    version=models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Version of the item')

    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date', help_text='The date of publishing', auto_now=True)

    item_type = models.ForeignKey(itemType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    stage = models.ForeignKey(itemStage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/static_dirs/images', blank=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalog:item_detail',                       
        args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

catalog\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, item


def itemListView(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    items = item.objects.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        items = items.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'catalog/item/list.html', {'category': category,
                                                      'categories': categories,
                                                      'items': items})

def itemDetailView(request, id, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(item, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)

    context = {
        'item' : item
    }

    return render(request, 'catalog\catalog.html', context=context)
```

list.html

```
<!--{% extends "catalog/catalog.html" %}-->
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}items{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <ul>
            <li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{% url "catalog:item_list" %}">All</a>
            </li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="item-list">
        <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}items{% endif %}</h1>
        {% for item in items %}
            <div class="item">
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if item.image %}{{ item.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                </a>
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.name }}</a><br>
                ${{ item.price }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I thought that it was because of catalog.html, which includes the navbar and title, so i commented it out. But now it shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not sending 'items' in context of itemListView function. you should use code something like this:

```
def itemListView(request, category_slug=None):
    items = item.objects.all()
    num_items = item.objects.all().count
    num_types = itemType.objects.all().count

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)        
        items = item.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'num_items' : num_items,
        'num_types' : num_types, 
        'items': items
    }

    return render(request, 'catalog\item\list.html', context=context)
```

Comment: thanks!!! i added items, categories, ...... and now it works